# Javascript: New variable name composed of value of another variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, syntax

Easiest to explain by showing code:

```
var delta_selected = false;
var magma_selected = false;
var aqua_selected = false;

// Somewhere in my functions...
if (sumthing == 'sumthing1') {
    topic = 'delta';
} else if (sumthing == 'sumthing2') {
    topic = 'magma';
} else {
    topic = 'aqua';
}

// Then assign it (so if topic is delta, then delta_selected = true)
topic + "_selected" = true;
```

This last line isn't working. Syntax error.

I need help to figure out how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just set **delta_seleted = true** instead of **topic = 'delta'**, etc...

Comment: If I could, I would. :D
I only posted some of the code so you can't see why I cant just specify the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
window[topic + "_selected"] = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use variables? Looks to me like you need a single structure that contains all your `_selected` values.

```
var selected = {
    delta:false,
    magma:false,
    aqua:false
};
```

then...

```
if (sumthing == 'sumthing1') {
    topic = 'delta';
} else if (sumthing == 'sumthing2') {
    topic = 'magma';
} else {
    topic = 'aqua';
}

selected[topic] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "eval()" function. You will probably end up with something like:

```
eval(topic + "_selected = true;")
```

But check the documentation to be sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I wouldn't want to use eval. Nice to know that I can do it like that though.